# replace multiple words from a string at the same time

Tags: python

I have this dict in python.

```
reflections = {
    'I am': 'you are', 
    'I was': 'you were',
    'I': 'you',
    "I'm": 'you are',
    "I'd": 'you would',
    "I've": 'you have',
    "I'll": 'you will',
    'my': 'your',
    'you are': 'I am',
    'you were': 'I was',
    "you've": 'I have',
    "you'll": 'I will',
    'your': 'my',
    'yours': 'mine',
    'you': 'me',
    'me': 'you'
}
```

I have written this piece of code to replace the words.

```
see = "I am going to kill you"
for i in reflections:
    if i in see:
        print(f'matched key {i}')
        see = see.replace(i, reflections[i])
        print(see)
```

This is the output of the above code.

```
matched key I am
you are going to kill you
matched key you are
I am going to kill you
matched key you
I am going to kill me
matched key me
I am going to kill you
```

Now I want to replace all occurrences of words from reflections dict and replace them. As you can see in code output, "I am" is replaced with "you are" and in the next iteration, "you are" is again replaced with "I am", which shouldn't happen. It should not replace the replacement. So the output should be:

```
You are going to kill me
```

Comment: You just need to indent correctly your `print(see1)` meaning outside the forloop. Now it's inside the loop that's why it prints twice. Also `see` and `see1` in the end wil have the same value so it's redundant to have both.

Comment: You should take care about order on replaces, cause if string is "I'm Wonka" and you want to replace "I" and "I'm"  only will match first replace

Comment: The mistake is not that simple. You see if I hypothetically correct the indentation level. After first iter of loop, one word will be replaced and next time it is replaced again with another. for example in first Iter, you are is replaced by I am and in next iter I am will be replaced by You are.

Answer (score 2):

###### Solution 1 - `str.index`

You can do it as follows:

- create a new string variable `new_see`, which is initially empty, but will ultimately contain the result of the replacements
- make each iteration only process the part of the input string up until the point where a matching key is encountered, and append the iteration's replacement result to the result string
- after each iteration, truncate the input string from its start to the index after the key encountered in current iteration, so that the next iteration will only work with the yet unprocessed part

```
see = "I am going to kill you!"
new_see = ""
print(see)

for key, reflection in reflections.items():
    if key in see:
        idx = see.index(key)
        print(f"matched key [{key}] @ index {idx}, reflection=[{reflection}]")

        # take the part of `see` up until the index where the `key` ends,
        #  replace the `key` with `replacement` and append the result to
        #  the new string
        new_see += see[:idx+len(key)].replace(key, reflection)

        # truncate the original string from start up until the index where
        #  `key` was encountered, so the next iteration will only work on
        #  the part of it that hasn't been processed yet
        see = see[idx+len(key):]

        # take a look at the intermediate results
        print(f"see=[{see}], new_see=[{new_see}]")

# append any leftover part that wasn't in the dict (in this case, "!")
if see:
    new_see += see

new_see = new_see.capitalize()
print(new_see)
```

Output:

```
I am going to kill you!
matched key [I am] @ index 0, reflection=[you are]
see=[ going to kill you!], new_see=[you are]
matched key [you] @ index 15, reflection=[me]
see=[!], new_see=[you are going to kill me]
You are going to kill me!
```

###### Solution 2 - `str.split`

Slightly more pythonic solution using `str.split` instead of operating on indices:

```py
see = "I am going to kill you!"
new_see = ""
print(see)

for key, reflection in reflections.items():
    if key in see:
        print(f"matched key [{key}], reflection=[{reflection}]")
        left, right = see.split(key)
        new_see += left + reflection
        see = right
        print(f"see=[{see}], new_see=[{new_see}]")
if see:
    new_see += see

new_see = new_see.capitalize()
print(new_see)
```

Output:

```
I am going to kill you!
matched key [I am], reflection=[you are]
see=[ going to kill you!], new_see=[you are]
matched key [you], reflection=[me]
see=[!], new_see=[you are going to kill me]
You are going to kill me!
```

---

As pointed out in a comment, this code is going to replace "I'm" with "You'm". In order to fix this, you should reorder the entries in your dict such that "I'm", "I'd", etc., are processed before "I". Even then though, it will still not work properly in some cases, e.g. for words in all caps - "DICT" is going to be replaced with "DyouCT". In order to deal with this, you'd need to take a look at regular expressions and use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) instead of `str.replace` - that will allow you e.g. to only replace a key if it's a standalone word (i.e. surrounded by non-letters).

Answer (score 0):

`print(see1)` has the wrong level of indentation.

Try with this:

```
see = "you are going to kill me"
for i in reflections:
    if i in see:
        see = see.replace(i, reflections[i])
        see1 = see.replace(i, reflections[i])
print(see1)
```

That way you print the word once you have broken out of the for-loop.

Comment: You have the rep to comment. This answers is not useful for future reference. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo

Comment: Sure... If that makes you happy (:

Comment: If for every simple mistake and typos we gave an answer there would be a chaos and it would be more difficult for someone to find what he's actually looking for.

Comment: The mistake is not that simple. You see if I hypothetically correct the indentation level. After first iter of loop, one word will be replaced and next time it is replaced again with another. for example in first Iter, you are is replaced by I am and in next iter I am will be replaced by You are.

Comment: Im really confused. In the first iter, "you are" gets replaced with "I am". And in the next iter "me" gets replaced with "you". What are you expecting to see happen?

Comment: In the first iter, "you are" gets replaced with "I am". And in the next iter "me" gets replaced with "you". You are correct till here but in 3rd iter I am is again replaced by you are because it is also in see. I want to remove all occurrences from dict at the same time, so that I doesn't replace again.